# Current and voltage

Tags: voltage, current, load

Suppose a 100W load works on 100V with 1A current.  Can the same load work on 1V and 100A current flowing through it? (Not considering circuit breakers).

Comment: What kind of load Dos you have in mind?

Comment: This depends on whether the load is current driven or voltage driven.

Comment: Those two operating points have same power but different load resistance.

Comment: Not even close to possible.

Comment: @ThePhoton that is incorrect for impedance for a motor, yet correct for same voltage and current, and a stalled motor does no mechanical work, Do not mislead him

Comment: @ThePhoton if you do not delete your incorrect assumptions that I indicated, you are denying the error.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, where did I say a stalled motor does work?

Comment: Your answer said one case is stalled but the question assumes does the same work, so that does not meet the criteria. FWIW @Thephoton

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, The question says nothing about "doing work". It says a system works (meaning, operates or functions) with a certain voltage and current. Anyway I will delete my comment because it's a waste of time to argue about this after the question has been closed for 4 days and the OP is long gone.

Comment: @ThePhoton it is not a waste of time to analyze errors and correct them so as not to repeat them. “Same work” “work load” “load works” practically mean the same thing in general terms

Answer (score 4):

For a resistive load, no.

If the load consumes 1 A at 100 V then \$ R = \frac V I  = \frac {100} 1 = 100 \Omega \$.

If you drop the voltage to 1 V then \$ P = \frac {V^2} R = \frac {1^2} 100 = 0.01 \ \text W \$.

Power is proportional to V<sup>2</sup> or I<sup>2</sup> so decreasing the voltage by a factor of 100 will drop the power by a factor of 10,000.

There are devices such as switched mode power supplies that will work over a wide range of input voltages but give constant power output. These have active electronics and will draw more current at low input voltages and less at high voltages. Typically these will work over approximately a 3:1 voltage ratio but not 100:1 as in your question.

---

To respond to @EloyCalatrava's comment:

> If I have, let's say a resistor of 100 W **if I can manage to supply 100 A with only 1 V** it will drop 100 W same as **if I can manage to supply 1 A over 100 V.** I do not see the difference.

Ohm's Law gives us a relationship with three variables, *V, I* and *R* and the equation is *V = IR*. If one of the variables is fixed as *R* is in this case then the other two, *V* and *I*, vary in proportion to one another. If *V* goes down then *I* goes down. If you try to push 100 A through the original resistor then *V* goes up by 100 to 10,000 V and *P* goes up by 100<sup>2</sup> to 10 kW.

Comment: The way how I understand the question is the following, I have a load able to handle 100W, it works ok by applying 100V and 1A, will it work if I apply 1V and 100A? Please do not be so hard with me but I think the reply is yes. If I have, let's say a resistor of 100W if I can manage to supply 100A with only 1V it will drop 100W same as if I can manage to supply 1A over 100V. I do not see the difference. I would really appreciate additional explanation.

Comment: @EloyCalatrava:  A circuit that works with 100 volts and 1 ampere is almost guaranteed not to work with 1 volt and 100 amperes.  The power is the same, but it is applied very differently.  Look at [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) and see how it connects with [Joule heating.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating)  If you don't see the connection, post your own question.

Comment: @EloyCalatrava:  Try an analogy.  A water jet cutter at 30 thousand psi can cut steel.  By your way of thinking, several thousand garden hoses at 10 psi should also cut steel.  Do you see a problem with that logic?

Comment: @JRE thanks for your comments, especially the first one, I will review the physics. But your second example I think is a bit biased, don't you think so? (I am sorry if I am not using the correct word, I am Spanish so my English might be wrong, my comment tries to be sarcastic with all due respect) If you could pile the 3 thousand garden hoses you maybe could get the 30k psi enough to cut the steel, isn't it? As said, I will review and post a question in case I cannot reach to a good conclusion. Thank you!

Comment: @EloyCalatrava No. PSI doesn't add up. PSI and flow rate are two completely different things. My version: If a water jet cutter with 30000 PSI and 0.1 L/s can cut steel, can a river with 0.1 PSI and 30000 L/s also cut steel? What happens if you put steel in a river, does it cut?

Comment: But, a water jet cutter can spin a turbine, and so can a river. But they need different turbines. The turbine that works in the river won't work if you point the cutter at it. The turbine that works with the cutter won't work if you put it in the river.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the kind of load. A device powered by a switched-mode supply can indeed draw the same power, whatever voltage is applied to it, in theory.

For basic loads like resistors, heaters, solenoids, etc, ... it won't work, because these loads typically react by drawing less current, when you apply a lower voltage (or, if the system is current driven, react by dropping less voltage when a lower current is applied). The other answer explains the physics behind this.

A switched-mode power supply (also called a DC-DC converter in this case), on the other hand, maintains the same power on both its input and its output. So, supposing a device internally needing a steady 5V and drawing 100W, if its supply is given 100V, it will draw 1A, and if it is given 10V, it will draw 10A. Whatever voltage is applied externally will be stepped down appropriately to 5V and the internal circuitry will be fed 20A.

However, this is theory. In practice, such power supplies have constraining min and max input voltage requirements, and the range of acceptable voltage is typically much more restricted than 100V down to 1V (especially for a supply as big as 100W). 1V is also a very very low voltage and there aren't many active circuits that can work down to this. Last detail: the efficiency typically varies depending on the input characteristics, so it is not exactly linear.

But there are some practical examples: a computer with a universal 110-220V supply makes a good one. If the computer needs 220W to work, it will draw about 2A when plugged in a 110V network and about 1A on a 220V network.

Answer (score 0):

If its a pure constant power load like a switch mode power supply and it will work at 1 V and draw 100A then yes.  Otherwise no.

For a resistive load, and to use a hydraulic analogy, Voltage is like water pressure and current is like the volume of water flow.  If you drop the water pressure by a factor of 100, as in this example, less water (=current) would flow proportionately.

Ohms law V=IR defines this.  If R is fixed, lowering V must lower I.

Answer (score 0):

In the theoretical world, yes. In the real world, no. It is not practical to design a load that can handle a 100x range of voltages. If you locked an engineer in a room and said they can't come out until they design such a load, then they could probably do it. But it would still not be practical.

The main difference between theory and practice is that in theory, theory and practice are the same. But in practice, they are different.

Answer (score 0):

It’s perhaps helpful to understand that a power supply typically provides a voltage, but the current is generally limited by the load.  By analogy, the water pressure (voltage) in a pipe is generated by a pump, but the amount of water that comes out (current) is determined by how much the tap is open.  In this example, a load that would allow 1A to flow from a 100V supply would draw 0.01A from a 1V supply, if the load is purely resistive.  Different types of load might have different characteristics, but a 100:1 voltage range would be technically difficult, although not impossible.